# Python3: set a range of data

Tags: python-3.x, range

I feel this must be very basic but I cannot find a simple way. 
I am using python3
I have many data files with x,y data where x goes from 0 to 140 (floating).
Let's say

```
0, 2.1
0.5,3.5
0.8,3.2
...
```

I want to import values of x within the range 25.4 to 28.1 and their correspondent values in y. Every file might have different length so the value x>25.4 might appear in different row.

I am looking for something equivalent to the following command in gnuplot:

```
set xrange [25.4:28.1]
```

This time I cannot use gnuplot because the data processing requires more than the capabilities of gnuplot.
I imported the data with Pandas but I cannot set a range.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`r = range(start, stop, step)` is the pattern for this in Python.

So, for example, to get:

```
r == [0, 1, 2]
```

You would write:

```
r = [x for x in range(3)]
```

And to get:

```
r == [0, 5, 10]
```

You would write:

```
r = [x for x in range(0, 11, 5)]
```

This doesn't get you very far because:

```
r = [0, .2, 4.3, 6.3]
r = [x for x in r if x in range(3, 10)]
# r == []
```

But you can do:

```
r = [0, .2, 4.3, 6.3]
r = [x for x in r if ((x > 3) & (x < 10))]
# r == [4.3, 6.3]
```

Pandas and Numpy give you a much more concise way of doing this. Consider the following demo of `.between`

```
import pandas as pd
import io

text = io.StringIO("""Close   Top_Barrier Bottom_Barrier
0       441.86  441.964112  426.369888
1       448.95  444.162225  425.227108
2       449.99  446.222271  424.285063
3       449.74  447.947051  423.678282
4       451.97  449.879254  423.029413""")

df = pd.read_csv(text, sep='\\s+')
df = df[df["Close"].between(449, 452)] # between
df
```

So for your `df` you can do the same: `df = df[df["x"].between(min, max)]`

Comment: Dear Charles Landau,

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added further information.